# pyspark throws TypeError: textFile() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I googled this problem, yet no direct answer related to spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7. I am trying to read a text file from local directory, but I always get TypeError that `name` argument is missing. This is the code in jupyter notebook with Python3:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext as sc
data = sc.textFile("/home/bigdata/test.txt")
```

When I run the cell, I get this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-7-2a326e5b8f8c> in <module>()
  1 from pyspark import SparkContext as sc
  ----> 2 data = sc.textFile("/home/bigdata/test.txt")
  TypeError: textFile() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are calling the [`textFile()` instance method](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.0/python/pyspark/context.py#L514)

```
def textFile(self, name, minPartitions=None, use_unicode=True):
```

like it was a static method which results into `"/home/bigdata/test.txt"` string being used for the `self` value leaving `name` argument not specified, hence the error.

Create an instance of the `SparkContext` class:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]"))
data = sc.textFile("/home/bigdata/test.txt")
```

Comment: Thank you @alecxe for your help. I tried the code you suggested, but I got the following error: `ValueError: Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once; existing SparkContext(app=PySparkShell, master=local[*]) created by <module> at /home/bigdata/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.py:186 `

Comment: @Mohammed ah, these `local` and `test` are there for demonstration purposes only..the main point is to initialized the `SparkContext` class. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(SparkConf())
data = sc.textFile("my_file.txt")
```

**Display some content**

['this is text file and sc is working fine']